# Batch to compress a folder with WinRAR's rar.exe. The file includes 2 unwanted empty parent folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, compression, rar, winrar

I'm trying to rar a folder. For some reason the resulting .rar file includes 2 parent folders, both empty, that lead to the folder that i want to compress.

This is the folder i need to compress: \PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver%\

This is the line i'm using

```
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
rar a -r -v2m -m5 "\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver% RARs\%ver%" "\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver%\"
```

And this is where the folder is inside the .rar. \Dev\Client\%ver%

Instead of just containing the folder i want to compress, the rar contains 2 empty parent folders (which on my system are not empty btw) the file is located on \PC2\deploy\Scripts\QA\, if it helps, but giving full paths to rar.exe should mean that i don't have any issues..

Any help?

Edit: -ep does not help since i have subfolders inside the one i need, and using it just drops all files on the .rar

Comment: Have you tried `-ep1`?

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the files you want to zip in a new folder and then create a zip. Since you are already using batch files just add 2 more copy commands before the zip command. You can optionally add a delete at the end.

```
    mkdir
    copy
    copy
    zip
    rmdir
```

Comment: mmm why? i need the entire folder with all its subfolders and content. I also need it to be im 2mb parts. Winrar does this, but for some reason it's including the folder i need inside other 2, which i don't and makes the uncompressing process more anoying.

I dont' see how moving the files from it's original forlder will solve the issue.. i need help with the rar command.

Answer (score 0):

One more question about: How to remove base folder from archived files and folders?

And once more the solution can be found in text file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of **WinRAR** or in help of **WinRAR** on the pages with title

- *Alphabetic switches list*
- *Switch -EP1 - exclude base folder from names*

The command to use is

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -r -v2m -m5 "\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver% RARs\%ver%" "\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver%"
```

which compresses the folder referenced by `%ver%` **with** including the name of this folder also in the archive.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -r -v2m -m5 "\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver% RARs\%ver%" "\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver%\"
```

compresses the folder referenced by `%ver%` **without** including the name of this folder in the archive. The difference to first command is the backslash at end of the path of the folder to compress.

The switch `-ep1` simply results in removing from the files to archive the path up to last backslash found on the folder path on command line. So removed by `-ep1` is

- for 1st command:  `\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\`
- for 2nd command: `\\PC2\deploy\Dev\Client\%ver%\`